# CSS transition with opacity only triggers onesided

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive navigation. The burger icon for opening the responsive navigation has an event listener which just adds or removes "responsive" as class to my navigation bar.

My problem is that the transition only triggers when I'm adding "responsive" to my navigation bar but not when I'm removing it. How could I accomplish triggering it in both ways?

http://jsfiddle.net/b5rxfnc4/

```js
let responseNav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__responsive--element'),
  nav__bar = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__bar')[0];
responseNav[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (nav__bar.className === 'nav__bar') {
    nav__bar.className += ' responsive';
  } else {
    nav__bar.className = 'nav__bar';
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 80px;
}

nav .nav__logo {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav .nav__logo .logo__image {
  width: 180px;
  position: absolute;
}

nav .nav__bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li {
  padding-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li:nth-child(1) {
  padding-right: 0;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li:nth-child(5) ul {
  width: 100%;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li:nth-child(6) {
  padding-right: 0;
}

nav .nav__responsive--element {
  float: left;
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li a,
nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li a {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li p {
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li p#p--link--kontakt {
  padding-right: 0;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li a:hover {
  color: #00a392;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li p:hover {
  color: #00a392;
  cursor: default;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 .dropdown-icon {
  float: right;
  margin: 4px;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level2 {
  display: none;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level2 li {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level2 li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level2 li:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level2 li a {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: none;
}

nav .nav__bar .bar__level2 li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

nav .nav__bar li .active {
  color: #00a392;
}

nav .nav__bar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .nav__bar.responsive {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
}

nav .nav__bar.responsive ul.bar__level1 {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  padding-right: 60px;
  opacity: 1;
}

nav .nav__bar.responsive ul.bar__level1 li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav .nav__bar.responsive ul.bar__level1 li i {
  float: right;
}

nav .nav__bar.responsive p {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav #p--link--start {
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav #p--link--kontakt {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
  nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
  }
  nav .nav__bar.responsive ul.bar__level1 li {
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  }
  nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li:hover ul.bar__level2 {
    display: none;
  }
  nav .nav__bar li {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
  }
  nav .nav__bar.responsive li {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  nav .nav__responsive--element {
    display: block;
  }
  nav .nav__responsive--element a {
    display: block;
  }
  nav .nav__bar .bar__level1 li a {
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav .nav__bar li p,
  nav .nav__bar li .dropdown-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<nav>
  <div class="nav__logo">
    <a href="">
            <img class="logo__image" src="">
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav__responsive--element"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></div>
  <div class="nav__bar responsive">
    <ul class="bar__level1">
      <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-angle-down dropdown-icon"></i>
        <p>Element</p>
        <ul class="bar__level2">
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-angle-down dropdown-icon"></i>
        <p>Element</p>
        <ul class="bar__level2">
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-angle-down dropdown-icon"></i>
        <p>Element</p>
        <ul class="bar__level2">
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-angle-down dropdown-icon"></i>
        <p>Element</p>
        <ul class="bar__level2">
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Element</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to add the transition to the normal state as well. `nav .nav__bar { transition: all 0.4s; }` will trigger one way. To have it work the other way as well, you also need `nav .nav__bar.responsive { transition: ... }`.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. http://jsfiddle.net/b5rxfnc4/1/